# How to get the total value from a 2D list in inheritance?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding

My objective: Extend the RegionalBank class by adding the method regional_total which returns the total amount of money kept in all of the banks in the region.

My problem: How can I put each value of 2D list on the parameter of instance RegionalBank?

```
# Do not alter this code
import sys
strings = [l.split(",") for l in sys.argv[1].split("*")]
accounts = [[int(n) for n in s] for s in strings]

class Bank:
  def __init__(self, name, customers, accounts):
    self.name = name
    self.customers = customers
    self.accounts = accounts
    
  def branch_total(self, accounts):
    total = 0
    for account in accounts:
      total += account
    return total

# Write your code here
accounts = [
              [10000, 13000, 22000],
              [30000, 7000, 19000],
              [15000, 23000, 31000]
           ]    

class RegionalBank(Bank):
  def __init__(self, name, customers, accounts):
    super().__init__(name, customers, accounts)
  
  def regional_total(self, accounts):
    return super().branch_total(accounts)
    
for row,col in accounts:
  print( accounts[rows][col] )
  
    
RBank1 = RegionalBank("Regional Bank A", 132, accounts)
RBank1.regional_total(accounts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your regional_total function with this:

```
def regional_total(self):
    total = 0
    for region in self.accounts:
        for account in region:
            total += account
    return total
```

At the end call it like this:

```
RBank1 = RegionalBank("Regional Bank A", 132, accounts)
print(RBank1.regional_total())
```

Explanation: The accounts property (you commonly call variables of a class property, whereas parameters are the input to functions or class constructors) of the Bank class is a 1D list, but the accounts property of the RegionalBank class is a 2D list (although they are named the same), because you just save the accounts regardless of what dimention it is.